# Is it possible to append a whole list of XML nodes without a loop?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing, lxml

If I want to append an XML node to another, I would do `nodeA.append(nodeB)`. And if I want to append a list of nodes to another node, I would do a for loop like:

```
for node in nodes:
    nodeA.append(node)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in one step.

PS: Python 2.7, lxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nodeA.extend(nodes)
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element/%22here%22) for more documentation on the ElementTreeAPI

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you can do it by just using nodeA = [nodes]  that would only work if nodes is already in listform, like this: ["1","2","3"] for example but that is with python3.4 though, i think it might work